# How should trigger the 5V relay with an ESP8266? Using PC817 or transistor? What are the pros and cons?

Tags: relay, opto-isolator, esp8266

I'm working on a product and need somd suggestions:

Which is the best approach to trigger a 5V relay from ESP8266EX WiFi module?

I attached both schematics.

In schematic 1, the relay is triggered using PC817 optocoupler.

In schematic 2, the relay is triggered using MMBT3906 NPN transistor directly.

[image: Schematic1]

Schematic 2
[image: Schematic2]

Which is best approach in terms of reliability and safe circuit.
What are the pros and cons of both approaches?

Comment: Can you define your requirements for "reliable" and "safe"? And what will you be using on the LIVE output? Is LIVE mains voltage?

Comment: Either is OK, but if you are operating the relay at 5V, it's marginally safer to use the coupler since the ESP operates at 3.3V. It'll work without it, but that level of electrical isolation depends on your definition of "safe." However, "reliability" is often gained by using fewer parts. In the second schematic, you could easily replace the BJT with a logic-level FET so you aren't drawing any current from your IO pin.

Comment: "best approach" would be to replace all that schematics with a single relay driver, like NUD3160 or whatever fits your relay current requirements

Comment: @awjlogan What I mean with reliable and safe is: In long term perspective, circuit must work and free with any issue to operate the relay. Here, LIVE output is LED Bulbs, Fan (200W) etc.

Comment: @KurtE.Clothier My intention to go with schematic 2 instead of schematic 1 because PC817 opto takes some space in PCB and I have no space for opto but on the other hand, don't want to compromise with "safety" i.e. as opto gives electrical isolation. That's why, I asked that what will be best approach which is safe to trigger the relay without using optocoupler PC817

Comment: @Maple your approach seems promising to go with single relay driver but worry for one thing: "safety or isolation". I read the datasheet for the same but want to confirm with you. Is it still require diode, resistor n all? Is it safe to operate 5V relay with ESP which runs on 3.3V and this NUP3160?

Comment: @MohitAgnihotri If you've read the [datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NUD3160-D.PDF) it is strange that you still asking this. "application diagram" on page 8 clearly shows that you don't need any additional components. It does not provide the isolation, of course. And if under "safety" you mean "circuit must work free of issues to operate the relay" then of course it would, assuming your relay coil is way under 150 mA. If not, then you need higher rated driver.

Comment: @MohitAgnihotri - "in long term perspective" is not a definition - how long, and under what conditions? Is LIVE AC or DC? And what's the total power draw? Opto couplers are pointless unless you need the isolation - there are cheaper, smaller, and faster (but you won't care about speed here) ways to protect your micro.

Comment: @Maple Yes, I checked the application diagram. Still asked because sometimes some strange issue face when deal with new component and want to confirm with you if you used this component in your design. Thanks a lot! Will buy the component and check. My relay needs below 50mA current.

Comment: @awjlogan It is LIVE AC current 230V and 50Hz. Actually, I designed commercial home automation product and this module will control electric load like lights, fan which operate on AC 230V. I generally use schematic 1 but due to space, I want to avoid the opto PC817. That's why, I asked that schematic 2 or other alternative is good option or not. Same product should work at least 5 yrs. So, asked for reliability and safety. Technically, we used ESP8266EX WiFi module which trigger the 3x (5V 10A relays) and we used power module which output is 5V 1A. Finally, what would you recommend?

Answer (score 2):

The first circuit:

- is used when the relay VCC is higher than the driver (in your case ESP8266)
- provides electrical decoupling protection

The second circuit:

- is good when the relay voltage is the same as the driver's
- has lower cost than previous circuit
- you might have problems making the transistor go into saturation when used with higher voltage on the relay

Comment: Both can work when the relay VCC is higher than the ESP8266. Unless there is a safety/reliability problem?

Comment: @user253751 As I want to go without PC817 opto because of space problem but don't want to compromise if PC817 gives better safety than schematic 2. What can be alternate or best approach?

Comment: @MohitAgnihotri the second schematic is good for your case

Answer (score 0):

But for the schematic 1, isnt suppose to be both ground isolate too?
I mean, if both have the same ground, all the point of isolation made by the optocouplers, is useless.

Comment: I agree with this, it does not look like isolated